# How i can move data from DB to my ViewPager?

Tags: android, database, android-viewpager, cursor

Class with DB and realization of Adapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {//implements 
View.OnClickListener{

ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
titles);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    try {

        SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Places", 
MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS places (name VARCHAR, 
time INT(2), solo INT(1), id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");

        myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO places (name, time, solo) VALUES 
('One', 23, 1)");
        myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO places (name, time, solo) VALUES 
('Two', 24, 2)");
        myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO places (name, time, solo) VALUES 
('Three', 22, 1)");
        myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO places (name, time, solo) VALUES 
('Four', 02, 2)");

        Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM places WHERE solo = 
1", null);

        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int timeIndex = c.getColumnIndex("time");
        int soloIndex = c.getColumnIndex("solo");
        int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");



        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            titles.clear();
            do {
                titles.add(c.getString(nameIndex));



            } while (c.moveToNext());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        c.close();
        myDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM places");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Class with realization Fragment and PagerAdapter:

```
public class MyGallery extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_gallery);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_gallery, 
container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) 
rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, 
getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class 
below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to move a field named "name" (nameIndex) from the database to the viewpager screen. I can not move cursor values ​​to a class with the creation of a Fragment. I read about the method of entering data into the List and moved from there, the number of the required position to the FragmentPager, but it did not quite work out. Can someone know a simple and elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: I cannot see the relation between the two files you've posted. If you need the data in the viewpager fragment, why not retrieve from db there itself?

Comment: Let pass this by class constructor to `SectionsPagerAdapter`, and then as parameter into fragment newInstance.

Comment: I put data from DB to cursor, then put it to array "titles" and set to ListView(did that, because build ListView realization before that), Than it took to me, to realize a ViewPager, but i never used it before. I don't understand what i must to pass, that my ViewPagerAdapter retrieve a data. Cursor, array"titles", arrayAdapter or position on my array..

Comment: @grabarz121 What i must pass to constructor? Cursor, array, ArrayAdapter or position on my array?

Comment: @Anuraag Baishya Сan you explain a little more in detail what concretely i must retrieve from DB to ViewPager?

Comment: @grabarz121 Thanks, I did everything exactly as you said, but the launch gives me an empty activity. And I didn't understand how my "title" array is linked to a sample from DB and the "strings" array that you created. I read that I need to add a .getReadebleDatabase command to fix everything, but I don't know where to put it and whether it will help me.

Comment: I recommend to use SQLiteOpenHelper and ContentProvider classes to manage your database. [Here's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm) some example.

Comment: @grabarz121 Big thanks man)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your FragmentPagerAdapter, pass an ArrayList to adapter constructor as argument

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new
                SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

In your adapter use a reference, and get string from array, such like

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> strings;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> strings) {
        super(fm);

        this.strings = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1, strings.get(position + 1));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return strings.size();
    }
}
```

And finally, in your Fragment class, pass it as argument, and get as a global variable from onCreate method

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private String title;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, String title) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        args.putString("key", title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        title = getArguments().getString("key");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_gallery,
                container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)
                rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format,
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Note. For better control on your code, if you have limited number of fragment, you should make an all cases using `switch` statement. Calling `position + 1` in you adapter may throw nullpointerexception, when an index of your array will be exceeded. You can start any postion using `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`, example of FragmentPagerAdapter with switch statement should looks like

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, strings.get(position));
            case 1:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, strings.get(position));
            case 2:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, strings.get(position));
                default:
                    return something...
        }
    }
```